# Return new incoming call uri

Tags: c#, vb.net, lync-2013

I'm using this simple code to get incoming call and Uri of caller. If user have multiple Lync sessions open it always return first one because of static index. How I'm able to get new connection index so that I would get proper uri of caller?

```
    Imports Microsoft.Lync.Model
Imports Microsoft.Lync.Model.Conversation
Imports Lync = Microsoft.Lync.Model.Conversation


Public Class myLync
    Private _LyncClient As LyncClient
    Public WithEvents _ConversationMgr As Microsoft.Lync.Model.Conversation.ConversationManager
    Public WithEvents _conv As Conversation

 Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Try
            _LyncClient = LyncClient.GetClient()
            _ConversationMgr = _LyncClient.ConversationManager
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
 End Sub

 Private Sub _ConversationMgr_ConversationAdded(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Microsoft.Lync.Model.Conversation.ConversationManagerEventArgs) Handles _ConversationMgr.ConversationAdded
        AddHandler e.Conversation.Modalities(ModalityTypes.AudioVideo).ModalityStateChanged, AddressOf AVModalityStateChanged
 End Sub

 Private Sub AVModalityStateChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ModalityStateChangedEventArgs)
        Select Case e.NewState
            Case ModalityState.Notified
                Dim Uri = _ConversationMgr.Conversations.Item(0).Participants.Item(1).Contact.Uri
        End Select
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

In `AVModalityStateChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ModalityStateChangedEventArgs)` the `sender` parameter can be cast to type `AVModality` from there you can access participant.

Excuse my c# but it would look something like:-

```
  private void Participant_ModalityStateChanged(object sender, ModalityStateChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewState == ModalityState.Connected)
        {
            var modality = (AVModality) sender;
            var participant = modality.Participant;
            var uri = participant.Contact.Uri;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I don't know if I doing something wrong because uri will return my own uri. Not caller.

Private Sub AVModalityStateChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ModalityStateChangedEventArgs)
        If e.NewState = ModalityState.Notified Then
            Dim modality = DirectCast(sender, AVModality)
            Dim participant = modality.Participant
            Dim Uri = participant.Contact.Uri
        End If
End Sub

Comment: Your code looks fin as far  as I can tell.  That event handler should be hit multiple times, it may be worth debugging/logging and getting a feel for how often it is being called.